# Debian Squeeze apt-get errors when installing Git?

Tags: linux, git, debian, apt

I'm new to Linux/Debian (squeeze). I'm trying to do an apt-get to install git and receive this error message.

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Package git-core is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'git-core' has no installation candidate

i tried editing my sources.list to the following

> # deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.5 *Squeeze* - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20120512-13:45]/ > squeeze contrib main
>
> # deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.5 *Squeeze* - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20120512-13:45]/ squeeze contrib main
>
> deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib
>   deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib
>
> deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/updates main contrib
>   deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/updates main contrib
>
> deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian squeeze/updates main contrib
>   deb-src http://http.us.debian.org/debian squeeze/updates main contrib
>
> # squeeze-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
>
> # A network mirror was not selected during install.  The following entries
>
> # are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
>
> # for your mirror of choice.
>
> #
>
> deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib
>   deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib

as i said i'm very new to this so i don't know what needs to be in the sources.list file. I can't actually install anything right now. i tried installing php as well and got the same error. please help :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `git-core` package is obsolete, try installing `git`.

**EDIT**

Furthermore you only have *squeeze updates* repositories in your sources.list, add at least one regular squeeze repository to get access to all packages, not just updated ones:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
```

Afterwards run `apt-get update` to update your local package index.

Comment: here is the command i'm using if it helps
[apt-get install git]